# Call a method in views.py from template

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I want to call a method in views.py from my HTML file in templates when the user is authenticated. I don't know what HTML syntax I should use here. I don't think a form or button would work since I want to simply call that method without letting the user click any button.

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- I want to call the method here-->

    <div id="user-logout">Hi {{ user.username }}! <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></div>
    {% block chess_page %}
    {% endblock %}

<!-- else redirect to the login page -->
{% else %}
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; {% url 'login' %}">
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to happen here. What would the method do?

Comment: I think you need to look into custom template tags or evaluate another options. Since it is a "templating language" there aren't "methods" to call, just a template that gets parsed and rendered. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways I could see this being done is either to write a custom template tag (something you should probably ask a specific question with your use case about) or use something like Ajax and POST to do something once the page is loaded with Javascript. You would want to do something like this:

This example uses JQuery

**Template Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "{% url 'thing_you_want_2_do' %}",
        context: document.body,
        method : "POST",
        success: function(){
           alert("done");
        }});
});
```

The above code executes a POST request to the given URL.

**urls.py**

```
path('/todoitem', views.thing_you_want_to_do, name='thing_you_want_2_do'),
```

This just routes that request to the particular block of Python code you want to handle it.

**View Code**

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def thing_you_want_to_do (request):
  #do thing you want to do when the page loads
  return #whatever you want to return
```

This does whatever it is you want to do.